# Use specific game tag when question is not directly about that game?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some questions are not strictly about a specific game X, but about other games like it. They may be tagged with that game's name. E.g.:

- [Card Games with clear cards similar to "Gloom"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/691/card-games-with-clear-cards-similar-to-gloom)

Others don't have that tag.

I'm conflicted about whether these questions that don't directly address a particular game should carry the game's tag. On one hand if I'm interested in game X, I may not care about other games like it and just want to read about X. On the other hand it could sometimes be useful to find relationships between games I'm interested in and others like it...

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your specifically talking about the mechanics a game has, I definitely think it should be there.  If there is a strong relationship between what the question asks and the game, I think the tag should be included.  Example:

[Games with features like Battlestar Galactica's “Traitor” Mechanic?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/92/games-with-features-like-battlestar-galacticas-traitor-mechanic)

If the relationship between the game mentioned and the question is vague, I think omitting the tag is fine.  The more specific our tagging is though, the better.  When in doubt, I would suggest adding the extra tag to the question.